# sliding menu in android stucks while open and close

Tags: android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

I am using nice library by [jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

But while opening and closing menu it got stucked first time after than it works perfact. And I am not refresh fragment if same menu is selected from menu only close menu list using

`getSlidingMenu().toggle();`

If any one has same issue and if you have solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you Activity:-

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
                MenuItem item) {
            // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
            // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

            /*
             * if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem) item)) { return
             * true; }
             */
            // Handle action buttons
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
        break;

            default:
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
        private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
                ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                if (position == 1) {

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else if (position == 2) {

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
```

For more information [Click Here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)
Here is demo code which helps you...

Comment: But in this there is no use of jfeinstein10 library